# How to show span when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my CSS:

```
.faqBlock{
margin-bottom:2em;
}
.faqBlock>span{
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.faqBlock h2{
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cf5630;
margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
font-size: 1.33em;
}
.faqBlock .faq{
margin: 1em auto 1em auto;
display:flex;
flex-flow:column;
line-height: 1.2em;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
.faq p{
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(123,26,29,0);
}
.faqBlock .faqA{
display:none;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
line-height: 1.2em;
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0px auto 1em 20px;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="FAQQBlock">
<div id="Service" class="faqBlock">
<span>
<h2 class="OldStandard inlineBlock">What You Get When You Order from Epicured</h2>
<span class="faqQABlock">
<span class="faq pointer inlineBlock OldStandard">
<p>Do I have to cook your food myself?</p>
</span>
<span class="faqA inlineBlock OpenSansLight">
<p> Nope! Our chefs have that part covered.</p>
</span>
</span>
```

**This span is one span of many, I have over 30 the problem is I tried this javascript, it usually works but in this case none of my spans are working, can anyone see what Im doing wrote?
Here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$('.faq').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
</script>
```

I want when I click on "Do I.."
the "Nope.." appears

Comment: maybe you are missing closing <span>?

Comment: If you add the missing markup and execute the script **after** the `.faq` elements are available in the DOM this will work

Comment: you can quickly check your markup via https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Where do you run your jQuery? Is it in the head or at the end of the document? You don't appear to have it within a document.ready call so you may be executing your script before the elements exist on the page.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $('.faq').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can this answer be accepted? It's copying my answer, not properly indendet and no explanation...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Markup and CSS is valid and properly indended. There were several missing `</span>` and `</div>` tags. Seems to work with that being fixed:

```js
$('.faq').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.faqBlock {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.faqBlock>span {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.faqBlock h2 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cf5630;
  margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
  font-size: 1.33em;
}
.faqBlock .faq {
  margin: 1em auto 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.faq p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(123, 26, 29, 0);
}
.faqBlock .faqA {
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0px auto 1em 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="FAQQBlock">
  <div id="Service" class="faqBlock">
    <span>
      <h2 class="OldStandard inlineBlock">What You Get When You Order from Epicured</h2>
      <span class="faqQABlock">
        <span class="faq pointer inlineBlock OldStandard">
          <p>Do I have to cook your food myself?</p>
        </span>
        <span class="faqA inlineBlock OpenSansLight">
          <p> Nope! Our chefs have that part covered.</p>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="faqQABlock">
        <span class="faq pointer inlineBlock OldStandard">
          <p>Do I have to cook your food myself?</p>
        </span>
        <span class="faqA inlineBlock OpenSansLight">
          <p> Nope! Our chefs have that part covered.</p>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No all the closing elements are there, but I just displayed a preview of the first span that is way there were no closing marks.

Comment: Ok. If you ask a quastion, please always provide a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).